# C++17 structured binding declaration in for vs if vs while?

Tags: c++, c++17

When I compile this code:

```
std::tuple<int, int> array[] = {std::make_tuple(1, 2), std::make_tuple(1, 2),
                                std::make_tuple(1, 2), std::make_tuple(1, 2)};
for (auto[a, b] : array) {
  printf("%u %u", a, b);
}

if (auto[a, b] = std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff) {
  printf("%u %u", a, b);
}

while (auto[a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff) {
  printf("%u %u", a, b);
}
```

With:

```
clang++ -std=c++1z
```

I get the following errors:

```
main2.cpp:76:14: error: decomposition declaration not permitted in this context
  while (auto[a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff) {
             ^~~~~~
main2.cpp:76:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
  while (auto[a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff) {
                                             ^
2 errors generated.
```

Why is `auto[a, b] = std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff` supported in an `if` but not in a `while`? Is there some technical reason or is it a "that's just the way it is" reason?

Comment: `while (int i; i)` won't compile either. It's not the structured binding.

Comment: Sure it is. The error message for that code is quite different.

Comment: @oconnor0: Then the error message is simply explaining the error incorrectly. But the compiler is giving a diagnostic for ill-formed code, which is what the standard requires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the latest draft standard for C++, the `while` loop does not in fact have an optional `init-statement` the kind that `if` and `switch` gained in C++17.

The formal syntax is:

```
while ( condition ) statement
```

In conclusion, the structured binding is not the issue here. Check [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter) segment of the draft for reference.

Comment: Ah, I see the `init-statement` in the definitions of `if` and `switch` at http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select

Comment: `while` loop with an init-statement is spelled `for` :)

Comment: It becomes large `for (auto[a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2); b != 0xff; [a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2)) {
  printf("%u %u", a, b);
}` and redundant. Is there a better way that you have in mind?

Comment: @Johannes I don't understand. OP wanted `while (init; cond)`, which doesn't work. I'm just pointing out that `for (init; cond;)` does (and is 1 char shorter).

Comment: @Barry but it won't update the variables, unlike the `while` version would. However I see now that there's ambiguity in the meaning, perhaps it's disallowed because of that.

Comment: @Johannes Can't do assignment in structured bindings anyway (yet?)

Comment: @Barry No, it doesn't appear that you can do assignments in structured binding delarations. The goofy thing about the if vs while discrepancy is that: `label: if (init; cond) { goto label; }` is valid C++ and is essentially equivalent to the unsupported `while (init; cond) { }` but more awkward.